# Creating edge lines between specific polygons

Tags: qgis, r, polygon, line, polyline-creation

I have a polygon layer containing habitat types. It looks something like this:
[image]
where dark green is forest, yellow are open lands and the other signatures different other habitat types. In order to get something like a forest edge-line, I'd like to create a line shapefile representing those linear structures where forest and open land touch each other. I could of course use the polygons to lines tool in QGIS and then select the forest edge lines by hand - however, my data are too large for this procedure.

Any suggestions on how to approach this problem in QGIS or R? Please note that - unfortunately - I am not familiar with python at all.

Comment: Would it suffice to dissolve the internal boundaries where the code is the same on both sides, leaving you with polygon features? st_union from the sf package?

Comment: Dissolve as a first step is a very good idea. I tried in QGIS with promising results. I wonder whether there is a QGIS-option to create the forest edge lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end, I followed this workflow:

first step:

- dissolve original polygons using fields
- polygons to lines on the resulting layer
- delete all non-forest lines

[image]

second step in order to delete the outlines where the original layer extend ends:

- dissolve original polygons without using fields
- tiny negative buffer on the resulting layer
- clip lines layer with buffer layer

The result looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Nice, you did this in Q? Can you share the data or a similar example, it'd be interesting to get the R code for this.

Comment: Yes, this was done in QGIS. You could use any set of overlaying polygon layers, I suppose.